# Как импортировать настройки Atom с одного компа на другой?

Tags: atom

Как импортировать все установленные пакеты и их настройки редактора Atom, которые были сделаны для одного компа на другой?

Answer (score 2):

Атом хранит все пользовательские плагины и настройки в папке пользователя:

Для Linux:

```
~/.atom
```

Для Windows:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\atom\
```

Её можно просто скопировать на другой компьютер или сделать автоматическую синхронизацию, например через DropBox или другое облачное хранилище.

Для этого надо переместить эту папку в DropBox, а по вышеуказанным путям создать [символьные ссылки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Для Windows из консоли под администрптором:

```
mklink /D "C:Users\username\Dropbox\atom" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\atom\"
```

Для Linux:

```
ln -s "~/Dropbox/atom" "~/.atom"
```

Не забудьте заменить *username* на имя пользователя.